# How to make an AJAX-request look like a regular, normal request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, request-headers

What parameters on a `$.ajax` must I set to try and mask the AJAX-request as a normal request? I guess it has to do with the right headers.

I think **a big part of the problem** is that when working on a local .html-file, jQuery sets the header-value for `Origin` to `null`.

**Is there any way to take out the Origin-header?**

At this moment **I'm getting different results from the same URL** if I surf to it through the web-browser and when I do an jQuery AJAX-request.

Comment: If you get different results, it's because the service desires that. Don't try to work around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) enforced by all modern browsers, **this is not possible**.

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that differs in an AJAX request sent with jQuery compared to a *normal request* (whatever you mean by normal request) is the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header that is added. This header could be removed like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { bar: 'baz' },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            'X-Requested-With',
            {
                toString: function() { return ''; }
            }
        );
    },
    success: function(result) {
       alert(result);   
    }
});
```

or globally, for all AJAX requests on your site:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            'X-Requested-With',
            {
                toString: function() { return ''; }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm doing a GET if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Seb Nilsson, no it doesn't make any difference whether you are doing GET or POST. In both cases the following code removes the `X-Requested-With` as shown in this live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AUGQJ/1/ (inspect the request headers with FireBug and you won't find a trace of a `X-Requested-With`).

Comment: I didn't find it before either. But I still think that Origin is set to null is a problem.

Comment: This does NOT remove the header, it merely sets its value to an empty string. The header is still sent.

Comment: This is wrong. An XML-Http-Request also sends an origin header.

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery doesn't set Origin Header. Only browser itself can do it. And jQuery(or javascript) has no power over this header.
2. here is a link about Origin Header cases set to null  [Null Origin Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv)
3. the only difference between jquery and regular request is indeed X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest you can remove it by hand or you can make requests with new XMLHttpRequest, or with fetch().

good luck