# Are there any browsers that set the origin header to "null" for privacy-sensitive contexts?

Tags: cors

The [Origin spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454) indicates that the `Origin` header may be set to "null". This is typically done when the request is coming from a file on a user's computer rather than from a hosted web page. The spec also states that the Origin may be null if the request comes from a "privacy-sensitive" context.

My questions: What is a "privacy-sensitive" context, and are there any browsers that exhibit this behavior?

Here is the full phrasing from the Origin spec:

> Whenever a user agent issues an HTTP request from a
> "privacy-sensitive" context, the user agent MUST send the value "null"
> in the Origin header field.
>
> NOTE: This document does not define the notion of a privacy-sensitive
> context.  Applications that generate HTTP requests can designate
> contexts as privacy-sensitive to impose restrictions on how user
> agents generate Origin header fields.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I've finally figured out an answer to this. There is at least one other situation where an `Origin` header may be "null". When following a redirect during a CORS request, if the request is redirected to a URL on a different server, the `Origin` header will be changed to "null". I suppose this is considered a "privacy-sensitive context" because the browser doesn't want to leak the original origin to the new server, since the client may not have intended to make a request to the new server in the first place.

Comment: There is no way around this. This makes AJAX-CAS logins impossible.

Comment: It's almost unbelievable how similar I found your question and thought process to mine. Our team faced an issue with CORS on web during preflighting of a POST request to access Auth headers on web, while not facing any such problems on Android. Which got me thinking why CORS is not applicable to Android. I found out that our Android guys hand't even heard about OPTIONS and CORS. Weird, right? I then went on to read the specs and found ORIGIN section and null string point and then googled if theres a security flaw to exploit null string in CORS.

Comment: This is not happening in 'Edge' browser, it actually send the actual 'client' URL originating the request. Ideally the it should be 'null'. A similar issue is filed as bug in Microsoft developer website, which is still open.
Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8680109/

Comment: Damn this is annoying. Spent a long time debugging before I found this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154967

by strobe@google.com

> This behavior is actually in the spec [1]. **See section 7.1.7 step
>   6.**

Unfortunately the convention of transmitting the string "null" makes it seem like it could be a bug; I thought so myself until I tracked this down :)

We could probably do a better job of explaining this in the inspector:

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#generic-cross-origin-request-algorithms

Comment: Upvoted but note that the current spec is at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ and the specific relevant citation is to step 10 of https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch, which reads *If CORS flag is set and actualResponse’s location URL’s origin is not same origin with request’s current url’s origin, then set request’s origin to a unique opaque origin*. The “unique opaque origin” means an origin that will get serialized as “null”. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ should not be referenced any more, because it’s been obsoleted by https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other cases related to [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) which can cause a `null` `origin`: https://webdbg.com/test/sandbox/frames.htm

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757 for details about what the relevant spec require

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation, doing redirects in ajax from domain A->B and finally back to A. As origin is null, CORS fails.

On domain A I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`, which seems to work, will need to test more.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of Access-Control-Allow-Origin, please don't do that