# How to handle 302 redirects with Origin header set to null

Tags: ajax, redirect, http-headers

How to handle situations when browser sets Origin Header to null?

> This happens for example in situations of "redirects across origins"
>   when I make ajax, which returns direct to different domain, and after
>   that I get redirected from different domain to the original(and here
>   browser sets header Origin to null).

In one answer  [AJAX call following 302 redirect sets origin to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193851/ajax-call-following-302-redirect-sets-origin-to-null) someone offers to set

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
```

But this looks like bad hack and vulnerability hole.

Is there any better solution to this problem?
thank you