# Why would the redirected url with the same domain encounter the CORS problem?

Tags: node.js, redirect, cors, fetch, charles-proxy

The situation is a bit complicated. I used the http-server to host my local code at localhost:8080. Then I used Charles to map a on-line URL（example.online.com/index.html）to my local url (localhost:8080/index.html) to share the cookies. Then I started a local node server as a mock server at localhost:9963, The mock server has implemented CORS settings. I made a request to localhost:9963/api/list use the Fetch Api in my local code, so the request was responded with the mock data with cors. Sometimes, I did not want the mock server to respond the mock data. Instead, The mock server redirected the request (localhost:9963/api/list) to the online api (example.online.com/api/list) with 307. The problem is that, When the Browser followed the redirect, a CORS problem occured. My confusion is that, why a CORS occured when the redirected url http://example.online.com/api/list is in the same domain with http://example.online.com/index.html.

the error is (the origin url is replaced by the example url):

Access to fetch at 'http://example.online.com/api/list' (redirected from 'http://localhost:9963/api/list') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

the fetch code is:

```
  const url = `http://localhost:9963/api/list`;
  const method = 'POST';
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": `application/json`,
    "Accept": `application/json`
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify(req);
  const credentials = 'include';
  const mode = 'cors';
  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers,
    body,
    credentials,
    mode
  })
```

the redirect code is(using koa2):

```
  const r_url = 'http://example.online.com/api/list';
  ctx.status = 307;
  ctx.redirect(r_url);
```

Comment: It’s a cross-origin request because the request URL `http://localhost:9963/api/list` has a different origin from the null origin that the browser considers to be the origin of the request. When you redirect a request across origins, the browser sets the origin of the request to null. That behavior is required by the Fetch spec. The browser marks the origin as “tainted” in that case. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-tainted-origin%E2%91%A0 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/30193851/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625354/441757

Comment: Thanks for your answers. There seems to be no good solutions to The CORS problem caused by redirections across origins. Then I have to use proxy instead of  redirection in the mock server.

Comment: @sideshowbarker can you help me with another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372953/how-to-make-the-browser-include-the-cookies-of-the-domain-of-the-host-origin-whe