# How to make the Browser include the cookies of the domain of the host origin when making a cross-origin HTTP request

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch, cross-domain, credentials

I made a cross-origin HTTP request from the website 'demo.home.com' to 'demo.company.com' using the Fetch api with the credentials set to 'include'. There are two cookies. One is 'cookie_home=123; Domain=demo.home.com', the other is 'cookie_company=456; Domain=demo.company.com'. As a result, the cookie 'cookie_company' was included by the request. Is there any way to let the cookie 'cookie_home' be included by the request?

```
// the request is made in the website 'http://demo.home.com'
// the cookies are:
// 'cookie_home=123; Domain=demo.home.com'
// 'cookie_company=456; Domain=demo.company.com'
fetch('http://demo.company.com/api/test', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch API with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558264/fetch-api-with-cookie)

Comment: It is a different question. it focuses on how to include the cookies with the domain of the host origin instead of the domain of the target url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `fetch` (and `XMLHttpRequest`) provide no mechanism to manually set cookies in a request.

They'll only send cookies in the browser's cookie jar for the target URL. This applies the normal rules for which domain a cookie belongs to.

You need to use some other mechanism to send the data you would store in the cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with your answer. I have to think of other ways to solve my problems.