# HSTS redirect sets Origin to 'null'

Tags: redirect, cors, http-headers, hsts

Client tries to access `http://example.com/token/` but `example.com` had HSTS header and clients browser redirects (307) to `https://example.com/token/` with Origin set to 'null' which is being blocked by CORS, but 'null' cannot be in our allowed cors origin.

The error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at `https://example.com/token/` (redirected from `http://example.com/token/`) from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

How can the issue be solved?

Comment: `https://example.com` is a different origin than `http://example.com`. And when a request is redirected across origins, the browser sets the origin of the request to null. That behavior is required by the Fetch spec. The browser marks the origin as “tainted” in that case. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request-tainted-origin%E2%91%A0 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/30193851/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625354/441757