# Getting an original URL before redirection in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website (example.com) which will be a hub for redirection from several other domain (example.co.uk, example.org... etc etc). These addon domains are other third-party websites that doesn't belong to me. The redirection from other domains was setup by the other hosting provider using `301` method.

The question is: is it possible to get the URL of where the user was redirected from? `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` definitely doesn't work over here.

Comment: this header might be just not send, it's not obligatory and one cannot count on it, the best would be to agree with other providers on some way they would pass origin manually or prepare different links for each

Comment: @mikus thanks for your responses, yes I believe this is the best way too. However I wish to explore if there are any other options available that can solve this problem.

Comment: How about using [Javascript History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and sending it to your server via AJAX on page load?

Comment: Have you tried setting up CORS headers explicitly?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv