# How do i fix this Cors issue. I'm really stuck

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors

I've been having the following CORS issue for days and I'm no closed to fixing it. The Angular app on localhost:4200 isn't letting me access the route to upload photos.

My backend is in Laravel

I can log in, register, and perform other post requests, but not this.

This is an image of my app.

[image: App]

This is my CORS middleware which is registered as a global middleware]

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
    ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');


}
```

Reponse Headers in network tab

1

[image: Network 1]
2

[image: Network 2]
3
[image: Network 3]
4
[image: Network 4]

Comment: Which backend r u using?

Comment: @bhagwattupe I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: Have you checked the response headers in the network tab?

Comment: have you chec with `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com/');` in your route file

Comment: @kuh-chan I've included images of my network response tabs

Comment: @bhagwattupe What do you mean by that in my route file?

Comment: yes but your `option` request status is 200 , its not a cors issue

Comment: @bhagwattupe If you look at the first issue it says blocked by cors policy

Comment: You can create request middle ware  check these link https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1

Comment: The code I have in the post is in a middleware

Comment: If you change `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN` to "*" do you still get blocked by CORS? This is related to the pre-flight request, which can be kind of tricky.

Comment: Yea I do. I'm told I can't use the wildcard *

Comment: @AndreMacNamara I believe that this issue is causing due to redirect from `127.0.0.1:8000/api/advertisment/{id}/create` to `locahost:4200/advert/create` as the origin is set to null with redirect. Check this post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397072/are-there-any-browsers-that-set-the-origin-header-to-null-for-privacy-sensitiv

Answer (score 1):

The images you've posted don't actually match the error you're receiving.  [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965272/1188377); note that it mentions the origin being `null`, which is what you're seeing in your error message.  The issue is that your requesting page doesn't have an origin because you're accessing it via the `file://` protocol.  If you want to use CORS, the requesting file *and* the destination URL need to be hosted.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin has to match the *requesting* file, specifically--not the destination URL, as you're attempting to do.