# Cors Html5 Jquery/SoundManager wierdness

Tags: jquery, html, soundcloud, html5-audio, soundmanager2

So I am having some issues with the soundcloud api and html 5 audio player.

The main goal is to access all of the publicly available soundcloud tunes using only html5.

I am using the following.

```
    //C# api call returning json object. Cut down version of the code as it isnt the issue.
    var method "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{0}/favorites.json"
    var query = "?client_id=" + soundCloudClientId;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    return client.DownloadString(string.Format(method, artistId) + query);
```

I'm getting back this from soundcloud. Cut down again for some relevant test cases

```
    {
        "Songs": 
        [
            {
                "Title": "Rio",
                "Artist": "Netsky",
                "Album": "",
                "Duration": "03:49",
                "Artwork": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000120037955-m8t78n-t500x500.jpg",
                "StreamUrl": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/210032350/stream",
                "Libary": "SoundCloud",
                "TrackId": "210032350"
            },
            {
                "Title": "FreqAsia x Nasty Wizard - Episode 01",
                "Artist": "Frequency Asia",
                "Album": "",
                "Duration": "17:50",
                "Artwork": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000120265160-sn1a4k-t500x500.jpg",
                "StreamUrl": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/210368447/stream",
                "Libary": "SoundCloud",
                "TrackId": "210368447"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Episode 023 - June 2015",
                "Artist": "Frequency Asia",
                "Album": "",
                "Duration": "44:15",
                "Artwork": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000120689935-24wvqo-t500x500.jpg",
                "StreamUrl": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/210995770/stream",
                "Libary": "SoundCloud",
                "TrackId": "210995770"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Porter Robinson - Flicker",
                "Artist": "Porter Robinson",
                "Album": "",
                "Duration": "04:39",
                "Artwork": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000086441918-ds0915-t500x500.jpg",
                "StreamUrl": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/160632928/stream",
                "Libary": "SoundCloud",
                "TrackId": "160632928"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This gets called via ajax on my page and then with the results I render out a bunch of html on the page with bindings to onclick function that looks like this.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' +
             widget.get("TrackId") +
            '/streams?' +
            'client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
            '&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: "GET",
        success: function (resp) {
            $("#myAudio").attr("src", resp.http_mp3_128_url);
            $("#myAudio")[0].play();
        },
        error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('something went wrong', status, err);
        }
    });
```

Where $("#myAudio") is equal to

```
    <audio id="myAudio"
       src=""
       crossorigin="anonymous"
       type="audio/mpeg"
       controls="controls"
       style="width: 100%">
        Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element. Woof..
    </audio>
```

Now this works for about half of my songs.
It works for Rio - NetSky - 210032350.
However for Porter Robinson - Flicker - It Does not. I get thrown the following error:

```
    Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/nwtEnjuJwESE.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vbnd0RW5qdUp3RVNFLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MzY4NDc2NDV9fX1dfQ__&Signature=JN5bWI9dRW6a-KAczl0tjeTdoKmSa5BS8eGdI3I9E~NX9N~L-E9M2LRuCSuOc0jN0vk53VodFvwtArHfnFpedZjlo-7fmRwKMcZd5LAkGvCww0OiAztuzk4GESmLF8zE8RhKOF5UlNCJNLPZYM2BLgZPuMzsfLeQSLGPDbCHkiJazXZYoPjWKS8x3AYq4IBuwrzHsDOPT3GJN0XU89ugCm8x-cEZX946udYeRNrTwVUsVpTGjXwBE8zxRIE8AZFssptJsb9rCDpq9AlSoVBmII7RqYC264R9eovCqH8OTHGrQaeCQ9sXncwckjLpa70bjouCT-1UV6ampEIs9wTaKQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

As a weird quirk if I remove crossorigin="anonymous" from my page (manually in firbug) after I have changed the src it plays the song(Correctly). 
Even wierder is that after that all of the songs play but with no sound >:S.

Removing crossorigin="anonymous" from the beginning has no effect.

However if I use the soundmanager approach it seems to work fine.

```
    SC.stream(
        "/tracks/" + widget.get("TrackId"),
        {
            useHTML5Audio: true,
            multiShotEvents: true
        },
        function (sound) {
            // This is Pure Evil
            $("#myAudio").remove();
            sound.play();
            var newPlayer = $(sound._player._html5Audio);

            newPlayer.attr('id', "myAudio");
            newPlayer.attr('type', "audio/mpeg");
            //newPlayer.attr('crossorigin', "anonymous");
            newPlayer.attr('controls', "controls");
            newPlayer.attr('style', "width: 100%");

            $('#AudioPlayerContainer').append(newPlayer);

            audio = $("#myAudio");
            audio[0].play()
        }
    );
```

Now back to the core of the issue.

Both the html5 method and the Sound Manager method hit the following url with a get request.

```
    https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/nwtEnjuJwESE.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vbnd0RW5qdUp3RVNFLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MzY4NDc3MDl9fX1dfQ__&Signature=w9wbiSg6eYJd6LESarJl4hbTNPwEMa0tV8q1rC30E~b5UcicVw~mkR6RfMaY4pYSE489nNFjXUTTPUYJ-2T6BHnarxBl8YcRsmAsRbp3BzI6AlkutzqV4LOTma0r08WA9CpuMRJRyOnfwA271sQeYz~FkKadkTs1zKTyBbKc~WxAQvqkfwXimYpAynWmGuw7mFc-AEXEQ9wwPDBj6EJD5R1NtvBPia-jtJEdfO39I4BIwGGLeu57xIQk0GcYWhJ2rEspmfDh~Z99dKW0H5tGNC3UyVGG7cb-PKiyVOkIdKRz3paqZ6~Xu65nMC5EVD1dc7T8~sYTLsUVJkNu~aySuw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ
```

Html5 Request and Response headers

```
    Host: cf-media.sndcdn.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
    Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Origin: http://localhost:58434
    Range: bytes=0-
    Referer: http://localhost:58434/Home/Main
    Connection: keep-alive

    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Age: 361541
    Cache-Control: max-age=252460800
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 4465057
    Content-Range: bytes 0-4465056/4465057
    Content-Type: audio/mpeg
    Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:49:29 GMT
    Etag: "b46b442c81cdb2d253827a19291d2847"
    Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 11:56:24 GMT
    Server: AmazonS3
    Via: 1.1 5c5638d5b5fb0e5b90e36788792360f2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Id: sSqydrdg2dAC7O1q3vUszcSKjd-qPAvtMbwijwwKF_MBZ3m1yHazcA==
    X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
    x-amz-meta-bitrate: 128
    x-amz-meta-duration: 279091
    x-amz-meta-job: nwtEnjuJwESE
    x-amz-version-id: RAqXwDop3vD2oYiHSW6PYUPyzsiuGp6H
```

Sound Manager Request and Response headers

```
    Host: cf-media.sndcdn.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
    Accept: audio/webm,audio/ogg,audio/wav,audio/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,video/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Range: bytes=0-
    Referer: http://localhost:58434/Home/Main
    Connection: keep-alive

    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Age: 361891
    Cache-Control: max-age=252460800
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 4465057
    Content-Range: bytes 0-4465056/4465057
    Content-Type: audio/mpeg
    Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:49:29 GMT
    Etag: "b46b442c81cdb2d253827a19291d2847"
    Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 11:56:24 GMT
    Server: AmazonS3
    Via: 1.1 b93cfa23ea94b492bc1948ec35e51f94.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
    X-Amz-Cf-Id: 6KjUx89xvaKdOIvl-7IcrnNhhhnCVr2Fk_1Co-S4vt4KdytC6GfJDg==
    X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
    x-amz-meta-bitrate: 128
    x-amz-meta-duration: 279091
    x-amz-meta-job: nwtEnjuJwESE
    x-amz-version-id: RAqXwDop3vD2oYiHSW6PYUPyzsiuGp6H
```

Note that Origin: exists in the first request and not the second. Now I have tried fiddling with.
[How to make an AJAX-request look like a regular, normal request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432320/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-look-like-a-regular-normal-request).

To get rid of the header but to no avail.

So to the actual question how do get cross origin requests to function correctly like they do in the sound manager?
/ is there something obvious that i missing that is causing this.

____  Json P Attempt as per comments ____

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/nwtEnjuJwESE.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vbnd0RW5qdUp3RVNFLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MzY5MjUxNDl9fX1dfQ__&Signature=bd0d9hCWuXTWtdkHMVJEAYMjOyT31G1nAt9Ak3A1kKHGvNu~Ix5SqJ75OHr~R1MlfaVX3scQoqu8LSTfRdZUgOKnzRVYUpZAIKBKC-vcmdy1LNW9ounvZDdgMU6o9th4wiO2fx3HEu~UDmrypW6SgmrHWt0Smp3S8l0ypt80iKESRJHdRYI6Y~dewta~f3CGe7Om8EfzO8ZDwieGVP2sxmrYCf6rnSNKwXtcH1OXmPdkcKEJiCrxNzL8xFfNI8ONXjHm6Vj05EFc6dYOEAIxvhMR6A~uqex7tytxFocrX9C0dCL~ND-89K7oSkWgBT28WgQ8fMySx7HTTHbc3gwd4A__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#myAudio').attr("src","data:audio/mp4;base64,"+data);
                    $('#myAudio')[0].mAudioPlayer.load();
                    $('#myAudio')[0].mAudioPlayer.play();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I would try to use JSONP

Comment: @CapelliC Unless im doing/understanding it wrong the jsonp request must resolve before I can start playing it. I will add a piece of example code which doesn't seem to function for me perhaps you will have some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the CORS issue, I think you're having the same issue as this fella' over here: [SoundCloud Api redirect confusion and Audio Api Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646525/soundcloud-api-redirect-confusion-and-audio-api-streams/30661326#30661326)

As to why it works with SoundManager and not your own requests, that's harder to answer. By looking at the SoundManager source code and judging by your use of firebug, I'm going to assume you're using Firefox. Firefox has (or at least used to have) spotty support for mp3, which leads me to think that your Firefox either doesn't support mp3's, *or* that SoundManager just thinks it doesn't (the html5CanPlay logic in SoundManager just isn't a fun read..), and thus downgrades to use Flash for playback. If so, the results you see could be because the request for the stream is done via ActionScript, which probably could generate a different looking request.

Comment: Alas Firefox I don't believe is to blame I have similar issues in chrome.

Atm I have switch to using sound manager completely which is working fine now I suspect your hunch regarding flash being the cause of the streams working is incorrect as I have tested in environments without flash, namely an ipad(at least i think they don't have flash) and I get the same results. I will keep digging :) thanks for the insight

Comment: Ah, bummer. True that iPads don't run flash, though!